# My Solr in JAVA code giving exception IOException occurred when talking to server at: https://solruatinternal.rics.org:8983/solr/#/ricsglobal

Tags: solr, solrclient

When i Hit url https://solruatinternal.rics.org:8983/solr/#/ricsglobal in browser i am able to see my solr is up and runing but when i hit this url from code
String URL ="https://solruatinternal.rics.org:8983/solr/#/ricsglobal";
SolrClient server = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(URL).build();
I am getting IOException occurred when talking to server at: https://solruatinternal.rics.org:8983/solr/#/ricsglobal

what should i do to get my error resolve

Comment: The `#`-part is browser only (it's what's called an anchor and never gets sent to the server). The proper URL should be `https://solruatinternal.rics.org:8983/solr/ricsglobal` or `https://solruatinternal.rics.org:8983/solr`.